# Add fractions using operator overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

In an interview I was asked to create two classes. The first abstract class is called Number, which supports one operation “+”. And the other one fraction which implements the "Number" abstract class.

Further: For a Fraction once added, it needs to be displayed in its original form. That is, 2/4 has to be displayed as “2/4”, not “1/2” or “0.5”.

No Other detail was provided to me.

Below is what I had tried (Incomplete).

My main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Fraction.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    Fraction sumFraction;
    Fraction n11(1,2);
    Fraction n21(1,2);
    cout << n11.getValuenum() << "/";
    cout << n11.getValueden() << endl;
    cout << n21.getValuenum() << "/";
    cout << n21.getValueden() << endl;
    sumFraction = n11 + n21;
    cout << sumFraction.getValuenum() << endl;
    cout << sumFraction.getValueden() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

My Numbers.h // ABSTRACT CLASS

```
  #pragma once
    template<class T>
    class Number
    {
        virtual T& operator= (const T &) = 0; // first parameter is implicitly passed
        virtual const T operator+ (const T &) = 0;
        virtual void display() = 0;
    };
```

My Fraction.cpp

```
#include "Fraction.h"

int Fraction::getValuenum()
{
    return this->a1;
}

int Fraction::getValueden()
{
    return this->a2;
}

Fraction::Fraction()
{
    a1 = 0;
    a2 = 0;
}
Fraction::Fraction(int num, int den)
{
    a1 = num;
    a2 = den;
}

void Fraction::display()
{
    // will display the number in its original form
}

Fraction& Fraction::operator=(const Fraction &num)
{
    a1 = num.a1;
    a2 = num.a2;
    return *this;
}

const Fraction Fraction::operator+(const Fraction &numberTwo)
{
    Fraction n1;
    n1.a1 = this->a1*numberTwo.a2 + this->a2*numberTwo.a1;
n1.a2 = this->a2*numberTwo.a2;
    return n1;
}
```

My Fraction.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Number.h"
class Fraction : public Number<Fraction>
{
private:
    int a1;
    int a2;
public:
    void display();
    Fraction();
    Fraction(int num, int den);
    int getValuenum();
    int getValueden();
    Fraction& operator= (const Fraction &); // first parameter is implicitly passed
    const Fraction operator+ (const Fraction &); // first parameter is implicitly passed

};
```

Below are my question:

1. Do I really need to pass numerator and denominator separately from my Main function for each fraction. Currently, I am passing it as separately to keep track of numerator and denominator which might be helpful while adding and returning the result in terms for fraction.
2. With my operator + logic if I add 1/4+1/4 I get 8/16, what is expected is I guess 2/4 which we get if we add normally. So how to add using numerator and denominator and to keep the fraction in such a way, so that if output is 2/4 then 2/4 and not 1/2 or 0.5.

Please help me.

Comment: [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/pre-algebra/fractions-pre-alg/fractions-unlike-denom-pre-alg/v/adding-fractions-with-unlike-denominators) can help with the adding logic.

Comment: I consider an abstract template class `Number` totally useless. Rethink the design.

Comment: I think I'd simply add the numerators while doing nothing to the denominator so long as both fractions being added had the same denominator. That way _1/4+1/4_ will be _2/4_.

Comment: It was the interview question so I had to implement using abstract class. May be they planned to add another "Integer" class apart from "Fraction" class which also implements Number class.

Comment: @Logicrat : It does not work, if denominator are not same,

Comment: The request to make `1/4 + 1/4 = 2/4` instead of `1/2` is silly.

Comment: @Unbreakable Well, no, not yet. But a `Fraction` class could certainly be extended to handle unequal denominators. I would think that good design would mandate _something_ reasonable happening if you were given two fractions that may or may not have the same denominator.

Comment: Your `Number` is not an abstract class. It's not any class at all. It's a class template. Your class template probably makes more sense in C++ than an abstract class and it may even be what was wanted, but it's not what was asked for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some remarks:

- you should not allow the denominator to be 0 because it gives an inexistent number (infinity or undeterminated)
- you should definitely **not** initialize the denominator to 0 for same reason (1 seems a more reasonable value)
- the correct (mathematical) addition of fractions is (*):

  ```
  a/b + c/d = (ad +bc)/bd
  ```

Instead of (or in addition to) the display method, I would advise you to write a `ostream& operator << (ostream&, const Fraction&)` overload. That would allow you to just write in you main

```
std::cout << n11 << " + " << n21 << " = " << sumFraction << std::endl;
```

I did not really understand you first question, but I would add a conversion from an int:

```
Fraction(int n): a1(n), a2(1) {};
```

to allow to write directly `Fraction(1, 2) + 1` or `Fraction(1) + Fraction(1/2)` (the first element of the addition must be a Fraction)

(*) this is the simple and general way. You could also use the least common multiple to get cleaner results:

```
den = lcm(b,d)
a/b + c/d = (a * den/b) + c * den/d) / den
```

That way you would get  1/4 + 2/4 = 3/4 instead of 12/16

But [computing the LCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple) is far beyond this answer...